# gdk_display_get_name: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed trying to run pidgin

Tags: gdk, pidgin

I compiled and installed pidgin on my MacOSx Mavericks, everything seem to went fine on make install but when I try to start pidgin from terminal

I get following error:

```
$ pidgin

(Pidgin:68719): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_display_get_name: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed
Pidgin 2.10.11

** (Pidgin:68719): WARNING **: cannot open display: unset
```

can anyone help getting rid of this message ?

Comment: What does `declare -p DISPLAY` say in that terminal?

Comment: `declare: DISPLAY: not found`

Comment: That's the problem. Your terminal doesn't know about your X server/session so pidgin can't connect to it. You need to export the correct value for `DISPLAY` before this (or any other X application) can work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to install Pidgin first I ran `./configure` with following arguments. `--disable-screensaver --disable-sm --disable-gtkspell --disable-gstreamer --disable-vv --disable-meanwhile --disable-avahi --disable-dbus --disable-nss --disable-gnutls` then I ran `make` to build a compile for my osx mavericks. then `make install` . In doing all the proces I discovered I need boost python binding, for which I installed boost via macports using `sudo port install libboost` . But when I tried to run Pidgin I got the above error mentioned in the post, so I discovered Pidgin cannot find the display required. For which I had to install `XQuartz` restarting installing XQuartz took a while and I relogged in and then `Pidgin` worked. On my OSx now the value of DISPLAY environment variable points to `/tmp/launch-DXOhcE/org.macosforge.xquartz:0`